# Why do the float elements not align side by side when using widths?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code below however am confused as to why the div element `rightnav` appears below the div element `leftnav` if I apply a width property to it.  What am I doing wrong or have I misunderstood the use of floats?

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTMl 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="&copy; 2012" />

    <title>DIV example</title>

    <base href="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />

    <style type="text/css">

    * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    #content {
        width: 700px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    #leftnav {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #000000;
        border-style: solid;
    }

    #rightnav {
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #000000;
        border-style: solid;
    }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="leftnav">left nav</div>
            <div id="rightnav">right nav</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image]

Now if I amend the code as follows by applying the property `width` to the declaration `rightnav`, the element appears below `leftnav`. I thought that it may have to do with the width of the div element `content` however there is sufficient width with the combination of both div elements i.e. 200px + 200px < 700px

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTMl 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="&copy; 2012" />

    <title>DIV example</title>

    <base href="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />

    <style type="text/css">

    * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    #content {
        width: 700px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    #leftnav {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #000000;
        border-style: solid;
    }

    #rightnav {
        width: 200px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #000000;
        border-style: solid;
    }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="leftnav">left nav</div>
            <div id="rightnav">right nav</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: @Travis J - What does it have to do with javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first example, #rightnav is not floating, but it stays at the right because it hasn't a `clear:left;` rule. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/5sHdg/

In your second example, when you specify a width for #rightnav, the browser has a explicit rule about the div's size, so it renders it as a block element should. But it doesn't float next to #leftnav because it lacks a `float:left;` rule. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Br4Lm/

So rememeber:

1. Use float in every `div` that needs to be positioned besides another one, thus overriding it's block element appearance.
2. If you expect to have a `div` element below divs that re floating, be sure to include `clear:both;` (`left`, `right`, or `both`);

Comment: Yeah, this is a good answer as well. Your solution does require a bit more work to implement; don't forget to clear the floats inside `#content` with `overflow: hidden;` or something equivalent.

Comment: Here are some examples of those "equivalent" soluctions: http://jsfiddle.net/P2XCq/

Comment: The clearfix solution is one often used because it comes with HTML / CSS frameworks as http://html5boilerplate.com/

Answer (score 3):

Adding `overflow: hidden` to `#rightnav` will solve your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/gCVaz/

An explanation of why this works can be found here: http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden

Comment: This will also take care of clearing the float inside of `#content`.

Comment: @Wex - Thanks. That resolves the problem but does not answer my question. Does apply a width without the property `overflow` mean that it will not flow next to the element floated to the left for example?

Comment: Well, think about how a (left) floated element works when placed before a container. All content that is inside the container gets pushed to the right of the floated element and then below the element. Notice how in your code, `#leftnav` takes up the entire width of `#rightnav`. In effect, there is no "right side" to push `#rightnav`, so it just gets pushed below the float. Notice the difference between what you've posted and what happens if you clear `#rightnav` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/6pQzU

Comment: Also, look what happens when you increase the width of `#righnav` to `250px`: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/V3kf5

Comment: @Wex - Thanks. When you say place before the container, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: In your markup. Floated elements will only do this special content-wrapping if they are placed before the container in the markup, as you've done with `<div id="leftnav">` and `<div id="rightnav">`. The effects are pretty visible as I've outlined in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005954/why-do-the-float-elements-not-align-side-by-side-when-using-widths/11006254#comment14384257_11006254).